# import polymer core-scaffold breaks google maps

Tags: google-maps, dart, polymer, dart-polymer, web-component

I have some working dart polymer code that shows a google map with some markers on it. It took me a while to get those to show up, as it seems the initialization routines are a bit wonky and it's as if sometimes there is not enough time to load the map div before it tries to render. Anyway, as I said I got that working. Now I wanted to put a core-scaffold around it, as they do on many demos. The minute I add this line...

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_scaffold.html">
```

...the whole thing breaks, i get the console error:

```
Exception: Class 'GElement' has no instance method '[]'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: '[]'
Receiver: Instance of 'GElement'
Arguments: ["maps"]
```

I commented out all other lines and reduced it to just that one.

Comment: In my first experimentation with core_elements 0.0.6, I had the same issue. I could not even make a simplest core-scaffold element working so I would guess it is a bug in the dart wrapper. I ended up writing my own scaffold. It might be worth entering a bug though

Comment: Yes, in fact I ended up doing the same thing. Trying to replicate the whole scaffold as my own component. I think I discovered the main gripe was with the line <link rel="import" href="core_icon_button.html"> within core-scaffold.html

Answer (score 1):

(As of today), using DartEditor 1.5.8 and upgrading to polymer 0.12.0

```
dependencies:
  polymer: '>=0.12.0 <0.13.0'
```

this upgrades core_element and paper_element to 0.1.x (was 0.0.x before). This now looks fixed (although there seems to be still issues with icon by ids) and I'm able to run a simple scaffold example (https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/example/core_scaffold.html). you might want to give it another try!

Answer (score 0):

I once ran into a very similar error message when I first tried to use google_maps and eventually figured out that the problem was that I was missing this line in my index.html.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```