# dart using google maps Class 'GElement' has no instance method '[]'

Tags: google-maps, dart

I'm trying to use google maps with dart, according to this web site:

```
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
Exception: Class 'GElement' has no instance method '[]'.
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: '[]'
Receiver: Instance of 'GElement'
Arguments: ["maps"] (package:google_maps/src/generated/core/base/lat_lng.dart:24)
```

My source code for .dart is:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

@CustomTag('rifidi-map')
class RifidiMap extends PolymerElement {

  RifidiMap.created() : super.created()  {

  main();

  }

  void main() {
        final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
          ..zoom = 8
          ..center = new LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
          ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP

          ;

        final map = new GMap(querySelector("#map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  }

}
```

The .HTML file has the import to use the script:

```dart
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
```

The versions I'm currently using are:

```dart
Dart editor: versión 1.8.3
gogle_maps dart dependency: >=2.0.7 <3.0.0
polymer dart dependency: >=0.15.0 <0.16.0
```

Does anyone have a working workspace that can share with me to see how to implement a google maps polymer component using dart? Thanks

Comment: Did you confirm that the file is actually getting pulled down? `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false`

Comment: Consider this is potentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984742/import-polymer-core-scaffold-breaks-google-maps

Comment: i think the issue has to do with the right place where this import maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false should be placed

Comment: Where is it now? Just add it in a `script` tag at the top of your `index.html` to confirm it's even the problem.

Comment: It is inside index.html, and if i remove that entry, i get the same error, it is like if it were not read from there

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do anything but local variable initialization in a Polymer elements constructor. Use the lifecycle methods instead.

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

@CustomTag('rifidi-map')
class RifidiMap extends PolymerElement {

  RifidiMap.created() : super.created();

  @override
  void ready() {
    final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
        ..zoom = 8
        ..center = new LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
        ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP;

        final map = new GMap(querySelector("#map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  }
}
```

I don't know the `google_maps` package. It might still not work.

Comment: Thanks Günter, I changed my source code, but i think the issue has to do with the right place where this import http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false should be placed